# Program not displaying anything after compiling in c

Tags: c

I made a C program to keep track of the distanced traveled by buses and hours worked by employees, both have ID as the primary key, these save on 2 different files. The code compiles but does not show anything, care to help? I used different sources for help with this code but I don't think that's the problem since a similar code runs well

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 100

int provbid;
int proveid;
int login();
void menu2();
void menu3();
void bus_mgm();
void emp_mgm();


typedef struct bus_data
{
    int busid;
    float distrav;

}bus;

typedef struct emp_data
{
   int empid;
   float hrswrkd;
}emp;

void addb(int*,bus[]);
void adde(int*,emp[]);

void viewb(int*,bus[]);
void viewe(int*,emp[]);
void updateb(int*,bus[]);
void updatee(int*,emp[]);
void deleteb(int*,bus[]); 
void deletee(int*,emp[]);
int searchb(int,bus[]);
int searche(int,emp[]); 
void readfileb(int*,bus[]);
void readfile(int*,emp[]);
void writefileb(int,bus[]);
void writefilee(int,emp[]);

int main(){

    int el = 0;



    emp eplist[SIZE];
    readfile(&el, eplist);

    int option1;
    int p = 0;
    p = login();
    if (p==1){
    printf("\nWelcome to 'Company Manager' user\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    printf("Please slect an option:\n");
    printf("1 for bus managment menu\n");
    printf("2 For employee managment menu\n");
    scanf("%d", &option1);

    while (option1 != 3){

        switch(option1){
            case 1:
                menu2();
                break;
            case 2:
                menu3();
                break;
            default:
                {
                    if (option1 != 3){
                        printf("/n Option is not supported.");
                    }
                }
        }
    system("pause");
    }

    return 0;
}

int login(){
int pwd = 12345678;
    int count = 0;
    int pw;
    while (count != 5){
        printf("Please enetr password. \n");
        scanf("%d",&pw);
        if (pw == pwd){
            printf("Password accepted");
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            printf("\n Wrong Password, try again.\n");

        }
        count++;
        printf("You have done %d chances out of 5\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}



void menu2(){
    int choice;
    int bl = 0;
    bus bslist[SIZE];
    readfileb(&bl, bslist);

    printf("Welcome to the bus menu.\n");
    printf("Please select an option:\n1: Add bus information\n2: View bus information\n 3: Update bus information\n 4: Delete bus information\n 5: Return to login menu\n ");
    scanf("&d",choice);
    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            addb(&bl, bslist);
        case 2:
            viewb(&bl, bslist);
        case 3: 
            updateb(&bl, bslist);
        case 4:
            deleteb(&bl, bslist);
        case 5:
            main();
        default:
        printf("you have not selected a proper option");
    }
}

void menu3(){
    int choice;
    int el = 0;
    emp eplist [SIZE];
    readfile(&el, eplist);

    printf("Welcome to the Employee menu menu.\n");
    printf("Please select an option:\n1: Add Employee information\n2: View Employee information\n 3: Update Employee information\n 4: Delete Employee information\n 5: Return to login menu ");
    scanf("&d", choice);

    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            adde(&el, eplist);
        case 2:
            viewe(&el, eplist);
        case 3: 
            updatee(&el, eplist);
        case 4:
            deletee(&el, eplist);
        case 5:
            main();
        default:
        printf("you have not selected a proper option");
    }
}

void addb(int *loc ,bus list[]){
    printf("Add bus information");

    int n =  searchb( *loc, list);

    if (n != -1){
        printf("This ID is already being used.");
    }
    else
    {
        list[*loc].busid = provbid;

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Please enter the total distance traveled, the number you have given will be accepted as km: ");
        scanf("%f", &list[*loc].distrav);

        *loc = *loc + 1;
    }
}

void adde(int*loc ,emp list[]){
    printf("Add Employee information");

    int n =  searche( *loc, list);

    if (n != -1){
        printf("This ID is already being used.");
    }
    else
    {
        list[*loc].empid = proveid;

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Please enter the total hours worked: ");
        scanf("%f", &list[*loc].hrswrkd);

        *loc = *loc + 1;
    }   
}


void viewb(int *loc ,bus list[]){

    int meh;

    printf("Showing information of all buses.\n");

    for(meh = 0; meh < *loc; meh++)
    {
        printf("Bus ID is: %d\n", list[meh].busid);
        printf("Distance traveled is: %.1f\n", list[meh].distrav);
    }
}

void viewe(int *loc,emp list[]){
    int meh;

    printf("Showing information of all Employess.\n");

    for(meh = 0; meh < *loc; meh++)
    {
        printf("Employee ID is: %d\n", list[meh].empid);
        printf("Hours worked are: %.1f\n", list[meh].hrswrkd);
    }
}


void updateb(int *loc,bus list[]){
    int tempbid;

    printf("Update bus information");

    tempbid = searchb(*loc, list);

    if( tempbid== -1)
    {
        printf("This ID does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter new distanced traveled: ");
        scanf("%f", &list[tempbid].distrav);

        printf("Distance traveled has been updated. \a");
    }
}

void updatee(int *loc ,emp list[]){
    int tempeid;

    printf("Update employee information");

    tempeid = searche(*loc, list);

    if( tempeid== -1)
    {
        printf("This ID does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter new hours worked: ");
        scanf("%f", &list[tempeid].hrswrkd);

        printf("Hours worked has been updated. \a");
    }
}


void deleteb(int *loc, bus list[]){
    int tempbid, meh;

    printf("Delete bus info");

    tempbid = searchb(*loc, list);

    if(tempbid == -1)
    {
        printf("This ID does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(meh = tempbid; meh < *loc; meh++)
        {
            list[meh].busid = list[meh + 1].busid;
            list[meh].distrav = list[meh + 1].distrav;
        }

        *loc = *loc - 1;
        printf("Bus ID %d has been deleted.\n", tempbid);
    }
}

void deletee(int *loc,emp list[]){
    int tempeid, meh;

    printf("Delete employee info");

    tempeid = searche(*loc, list);

    if(tempeid == -1)
    {
        printf("This ID does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(meh = tempeid; meh < *loc; meh++)
        {
            list[meh].empid = list[meh + 1].empid;
            list[meh].hrswrkd = list[meh + 1].hrswrkd;
        }

        *loc = *loc - 1;
        printf("Employee ID %d has been deleted.\n", tempeid);
    }
}


int searchb(int loc, bus list[]){
    int meh;

    printf("Enter bus ID: ");
    scanf("&d", provbid);

    for(meh=0; meh<loc; meh++){
        if(list[meh].busid == provbid)
        return meh;
    }
    return -1;
}

int searche(int loc ,emp list[]){
    int meh;

    printf("Enter employee ID: ");
    scanf("&d", proveid);

    for(meh=0; meh<loc; meh++){
        if(list[meh].empid == proveid)
        return meh;
    }
    return -1;
} 


void readfileb(int *loc, bus list[]){
    FILE *bd;

    bd = fopen("Bus Data.txt", "r");
    if(bd != NULL)
    {
        while(!feof(bd))
        {
            fscanf(bd, "%d %f ", &list[*loc].busid, &list[*loc].distrav);
            *loc = *loc + 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(bd);
}

void readfile(int *loc, emp list[]){
    FILE *ed;

    ed = fopen("Employee Data.txt", "r");
    if(loc != NULL)
    {
        while(!feof(ed))
        {
            fscanf(ed, "%d %f ", &list[*loc].empid, &list[*loc].hrswrkd);
            *loc = *loc + 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(ed);
}
```

Comment: No output? Not even "Welcome to 'Company Manager"? Or "Please slect an option:"?

Comment: Step through with your debugger.  For starters, readfile() can fail silently...

Comment: You ignore the return value of `scanf()`  at your own risk.

Comment: Look closely at your `scanf` format strings: The format specifiers are interoduced by a percent sign, `%`, but you use an ampersand. (Perhaps you got confused with using an ampersan to get the address of a variable, which is also necessary in most `scanf` formats.)

Comment: Unfortunalely, warnings are off by default in many C compilers. Activate them (usually with `-Wall` or `/Wall`) and you will get useful warnings about how there are too many arguments for your `scanf`s.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, the first problem was with scanf which I did not see so thank you for pointing it out and the other is the first 3 lines of main, the `int el = 0;` `emp eplist[SIZE];`and `readfile(&el, eplist);` were not supposed to be in this function.